# Python 3: how to plot 39 K-means clusters, all with a different color?

Tags: python, python-3.x, k-means

I have a dataframe "hvc_hvposition", with the location of my customers (longitude and latitude). I want to segment these customers in 39 groups, using K-means clustering. Then, i want to plot these customers with a scatterplot, each with the color of their cluster. This is the code i have so far, but i can't seem to figure out how to get the colors right.

```
#K-means clustering of customers
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from matplotlib import colors as mcolors
colors = dict(mcolors.BASE_COLORS,**mcolors.CSS4_COLORS)
km_model = KMeans(n_clusters=39)
km_model.fit(hvc_hvposition[["LAT", "LONG"]])
cluster_labels = km_model.predict(hvc_hvposition[["LAT", "LONG"]])

   
# get the cluster color for each customer
cluster_colors = [colors[label] for label in enumerate(cluster_labels)]

# plot the customer locations with the corresponding colors
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.scatter(postcodes_df["LONG"], postcodes_df["LAT"], s=2)
plt.scatter(hvc_hvposition["LAT"], hvc_hvposition["LONG"], color=cluster_colors, s=6)
plt.show()
```

This is the error i get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-4c87d95de9db> in <module>
     29 
     30 # get the cluster color for each customer
---> 31 cluster_colors = [colors[label] for label in enumerate(cluster_labels)]
     32 
     33 # plot the customer locations with the corresponding colors

<ipython-input-3-4c87d95de9db> in <listcomp>(.0)
     29 
     30 # get the cluster color for each customer
---> 31 cluster_colors = [colors[label] for label in enumerate(cluster_labels)]
     32 
     33 # plot the customer locations with the corresponding colors

KeyError: (0, 15)
```

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you really expect people to be able to differentiate 39 colors in a plot? I'd wager that is impossible. At least use something like a combination of different markers and colors? Still, 39 is a lot... 5 different markers with 8 colors sounds a lot more doable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you try to extract the color values for the dictionary is the issue. Instead of `cluster_colors = [colors[label] for label in enumerate(cluster_labels)]`, try:

```
col = [c for c in colors.values()]
cluster_colors = [col[index] for index in cluster_labels]
```